# Android - Translate animation works first time but not second

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an animation which essentially sorts numbered balls by translating the X value. It works the first time great, but when i generate new numbers and attempt to sort again it doesn't work as intended.

The first gif is it working properly.

https://giphy.com/gifs/igyw5gvPtbmEOZqoBP

So here I tap the sort button and the balls are sorted properly.

In the next gif I generate new number and then attempt to sort but as you can see I get some strange behaviour.

http://www.giphy.com/gifs/kAuH2ZnnNCRX6bPKto

It's almost as if it's using the old X value to translate on.

Here is the sort method which triggers the animaton

```
  private fun sort() {
        val animator = AnimatorSet()

        val sorted = balls.sortedBy { x -> x.value }

        sorted.forEachIndexed { index, ball ->
            if (balls[index] == ball) {
                return@forEachIndexed
            }

            val occupyingBall = balls[index]
            val startingPos = balls.indexOf(ball)

            // move starting ball to occupying ball
            val occupyingRect = calculateRectOnScreen(occupyingBall)
            val startingRect = calculateRectOnScreen(ball)

            val move = getMoveAnimation(ball, startingPos, balls.indexOf(occupyingBall), occupyingRect, startingRect)
            animator.play(move)

            animator.start()
        }

        balls.clear()
        balls.addAll(sorted)
    }
```

Here is the `getMoveAnimation` method which create the object animator.

```
private fun getMoveAnimation(view: View, startingIndex: Int, finishingIndex: Int, rect1: RectF, rect2: RectF): ObjectAnimator {
        val distance = if (startingIndex > finishingIndex) {
            // Move left
            -Math.abs(rect1.right - rect2.right)
        } else {
            // Move right
            Math.abs(rect1.right - rect2.right)
        }

        return ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", distance)
    }
```

And here is the `calculateRectOnScreen` method for calculating the distance between the views

```
 private fun calculateRectOnScreen(view: View): RectF {
        val location = IntArray(2)
        view.getLocationOnScreen(location)
        return RectF(location[0].toFloat(), location[1].toFloat(), (location[0] + view.measuredWidth).toFloat(), (location[1] + view.measuredHeight).toFloat())
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to add view.getTranslationX to location[0].toFloat? I'm not familiar with getLocationOnScreen() so, I'm not sure if it returns only the original position of the View or it is able to "compensate" offset added by the translation

Comment: @W0rmH0le Yeah i did try that but it had no affect.